# how can cancel all operations in NSOperationsQueue and removing all operations from queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

```
[self.operationsQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];  
[self.operationsQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

This does not achieve what I want.

How can I cancel all operations in `NSOperationsQueue` and remove all operations from queue?

Comment: The call to `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` blocks until all operations are done. Attempting to cancel operations after that is pointless since they are all done at that point.

Comment: i don't understand you mean after all operation done make cancel .?

Comment: `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` doesn't return until all operations are complete. By the time your code reaches your call to `cancelAllOperations`, there are no more operations left on the queue. There is nothing left to cancel.

Comment: In short, just call `cancelAllOperations`. Don't call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`.

Comment: there is no any  benefit or reason  to use cancelAllOperations 
because didn't stop the operations in queue ,while it wait to implement all operations .

assume i use cancelAllOperations the operations is wait to done 
cancelAllOperations id didn't Achieved any thing .? 
strange case .?!

Comment: If `cancelAllOperations` doesn't cancel all of the operations then the operations are not coded properly. An operation must be coded properly to stop running if it has been cancelled.

Comment: In the case of block operations, cancelling has no effect, as blocks submitted as operations have no access to the operation object.  (You can work around this, but the general usage pattern does not include pre-creating the operation object.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `[self.operationsQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]`.

`[self.operationsQueue cancelAllOperations]` just sets `isCancelled = YES` on all the operations in the queue, it is up to the operations themselves to react to this.

So all you need to do is check `self.isCancelled` periodically as they run.

```
- (void)main
{
    if (self.isCancelled) {
        return;
    }

    // Do some work

    if (self.isCancelled) {
        return;
    }

    // Do some more work
}
```